# How do I slice a video with Shotcut into 10 parts?

Tags: video

I have a video that I want to slice into 10 parts. I want to select the parts of the video that make up one part with the the mouse and then let Shotcut save those parts.

Unfortunately, I don't see an export menu point when I rightclick on a segment in the timeline. Is there a way to do what I want in Shotcut?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you want to **cut** a video into 10 clips? What do you want to **splice** (ie join together)? Are you confusing **splice** (_kleben_) and **slice** (_schneiden_), which have opposite meanings? Oddly, it seems that _spleißen_ can be used in either sense.

Comment: Hah, 'cut' can *also* mean both 'split' (in the general sense) and 'join' (in film industry sense); not that it's terribly relevant to the question...

Comment: @AFH : Yes, I meant slice.